# Python Pandas combine multiple boolean series

Tags: python, pandas, list, functional-programming

I have a dataframe with multiple columns such as below

| gender | marital | education |
| --- | --- | --- |
| male | single | tertiary |

I have a list of requirements that contain boolean series and I need to combine them all using & sign.

```
bool_gender = df["gender"] == "male"
bool_marital = df["marital"] == "married"
bool_education = df["education"] == "secondary"
[bool_gender, bool_marital, bool_education]
```

How can I combine all of the items in the list using functional programming in Python 3 to obtain a single boolean value that is the result of the following expression:

```
desired output = bool_gender & bool_marital & bool_education


Possible use: 

reduce("&", map(function, iter))
```

Comment: You can also directly filter the dataframe: `df[bool_gender & bool_marital & bool_education]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this with the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.and_) module and [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function:

```
>>> import operator
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> lst = [True, True, False]
>>> reduce(operator.and_,lst)
False
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it preserves the data type (in this case Pandas Series)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) version of [`numpy.bitwise_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html):

```
np.bitwise_and.reduce([bool_gender, bool_marital, bool_education])
```

Comment: this is also good answer, but it gives me a numpy array.

Comment: @matt.aurelio well, you should not have a single value as you have a 2D input (DataFrame). You should have a single value **per row**. What should be the input if you had more rows?

Comment: what do you mean "if you had more rows"?

Comment: The provided example has a single row (male/single/tertiary), what if you had 5 rows? What would be the expected output? For instance with this input: `df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male'], 'marital': ['single', 'married', 'married', 'married', 'married'], 'education': ['tertiary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'secondary', 'secondary']})`